# Informatica powerexchange source

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange, informatica-cloud

I am working in a development environment developing in percentage my source is powerexchange. I am going to migrate to another environment UAT. And the source will change to a more accurate data. Can I migrate data maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.
If you have Oracle as source , no need to use the DTLURDMO utility. You can just change  the ORACLEID in the dbmover.cfg file. 
for example:

```
ORACLEID =(SCHEMA_SUDO_NAME,SID,SID,SID)
```

Where SCHEMA_SUDO_NAME is the instance name you use in the DTLUCBRG utility. This is also name in the xtramaps(after d8).

If you have other sources like db2 , you need to use the DTLURDMO utility.

Answer (score 0):

As the source schemaname is coded into the extraction map and the capture registration, you will need to run dtlurdmo tool in order to replace the source schema from dev with the source schema on prod